# Span element left and right padding reverses in IE7

Tags: asp.net, css, compatibility, padding, right-to-left

I'm having this really strange problem with the CSS of my custom validator.
I have a custom validator with the display property set to dynamic and the CSSclass property set to a CSS class I wrote.

In this CSS class I have a padding property. My problem is that the left and right values of the padding just reverse for no reason when I view my website in IE7 or IE8 with compatibility view set to on.
The values just flip, the amount of pixels set to the left padding appear on the right and the other way around.

Sorry for not posting the code, I'm writing this from my phone because we don't have Internet access in this network.

Any ideas?

Comment: with out the code this will be a hard run

Comment: Are you using right-to-left text on the page?

Comment: I AM using right to left text but it's the first time I had this problem. I tried setting "Direction: ltr" in a bunch of different places but it didn't help.

By the way, I noticed this happens to all SPAN elements on my page.
The custom validator is generated into span so...

Comment: Ok, that was just a lucky guess on my part. I have no experience with rtl text, so I can't give any concrete help, but a quick google shows that IE has many problems with it. You should try to build an example page showing the problem and add more details to your question - especially mentioning rtl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with span containing arabic text within an anchor tag - padding was inverted. Changing text to latin was one way to fix it :) Another one was to add `zoom:1` to that span.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing any code...I can only assume that the default margin and padding values are being interpreted differently by each of the browsers. I'd recommend adding a css reset stylesheet just above your other stylesheet to see if that changes anything?

CSS RESET STYLESHEET: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Hope that helps a little. :)

Comment: By "just above" you mean another LINK element on my page?
If so.. it didn't help.. =\

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, at least you can rule prestyled browser specific elements as a potential cause. Could you provide a link to the page in question?